# Guardar Archivos en Byte y subir a BD

Tags: c#, sql-server, base-de-datos, mvc, entity-framework

Muchachos Porfavor Alguien me podria solucionar la duda de como puedo pasar un archivo (doc ,pdf,jpg ,etc) y guardarlo en una variable byte para subirla a la base de datos
lo siento si no soy muy claro apenas estoy iniciando en esto de la programación

Answer (score 0):

Para leer un archivo y almacenarlo en una variable de arreglo de bytes puedes ocupar esto:

```
  string filename = @"c:\miArchivo.txt";
  byte[] bytesArchivo = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
```

Si esa variable deseas guardarla en BD por ejemplo, en SQL puedes ocupar un codigo similar a este:

```
 string queryStmt = "INSERT INTO MiTablaBD(campoArchivo) VALUES(@campoArchivo)";

        using (SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=TU_IP;Initial Catalog=NOMBRE_DE_TU_BD;User ID=TU_USUARIO;Password=TU_PASSWORD;"))
        using (SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStmt, _con))
        {
            SqlParameter param = _cmd.Parameters.Add("@campoArchivo", SqlDbType.VarBinary);
            param.Value = bytesArchivo;

            _con.Open();
            _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            _con.Close();
        }
```

Saludos!